# How to print class variables - java

Tags: java, class, instantiation

I'm meant to be making a base class (vehicle) with 2 derived classes (car + motorbike), which both contain certain information about each vehicle.

I'm trying to instantiate the classes, but am not sure what this involves. I'm assuming i'm meant to use the toString method.

After, I'd like to print each detail about each vehicle to the console.

This is my base class:

```
package assignment2;

public class Vehicle {

  int seatNumber;
  int numberMade;
  int yearMade;

  public Vehicle() {}

  public Vehicle(int seatNumber, int numberMade, int yearMade) {
    this.seatNumber = seatNumber;
    this.numberMade = numberMade;
    this.yearMade = yearMade;
  }

  public int getSeatNumber() {
    return seatNumber;
  }

  public int getNumberMade() {
    return numberMade;
  }

  public int getYearMade() {
    return yearMade;
  }
}
```

This is one of my derived classes (Car):

```
package assignment2;

public class Car extends Vehicle {
    public int topSpeed;

    public Car (int startSpeed, //top speed
            int startNumber,    //number of seats
            int startMade,      //number made
            int startYearMade) { //year made
        super(startNumber,startMade, startYearMade);
        topSpeed = startSpeed;
    }

  public Car(int seatNumber, int numberMade, int yearMade) {
    this.seatNumber = 4;
    this.numberMade = 1500000;
    this.yearMade= 1990;
    this.topSpeed = 180;
  }
}
```

This is another derived class, motorbike:

```
package assignment2;

public class Motorbike extends Vehicle{

    public int topSpeed;

    public Motorbike (int startSpeed, //top speed
            int startNumber,    //number of seats
            int startMade,      //number made
            int startYearMade) { //year made

        super(startNumber,startMade, startYearMade);
        topSpeed = startSpeed;
    }

  public Motorbike(int seatNumber, int numberMade, int yearMade) {
    this.seatNumber = 1;
    this.numberMade = 5000;
    this.yearMade= 2015;
    this.topSpeed = 300;
    }
}
```

This is my main class:

```
package assignment2;

public class Assignment2 {


  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int Car;
    Car = new Vehicle().seatNumber;
    Car = new Vehicle().numberMade;
    Car = new Vehicle().yearMade;

    System.out.println(Car);
  }
}
```

Any help regarding my code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT

Do I override using the ToString method in each class? I.E.

```js
package assignment2;

public class Car extends Vehicle {
    public int topSpeed;
    
    public Car (int startSpeed, //top speed
            int startNumber,    //number of seats
            int startMade,      //number made
            int startYearMade) { //year made
        super(startNumber,startMade, startYearMade);
        topSpeed = startSpeed;
    }
    
  public Car(int seatNumber, int numberMade, int yearMade) {
    this.seatNumber = seatNumber; //takes the value you pass as parameter
    this.numberMade = numberMade; // and stores it into the instance variable
    this.yearMade= yearMade;
    this.topSpeed = 100;
  }
  
  @Override
  public String toString(){
        return Car.class.toString();
      
  }
}
```

Comment: Either access the variables one by one and print them this way, or overwrite the `ToString` of the desired class and return what you want to print

Comment: Override the toString method.

Comment: "I'm trying to instantiate the classes, but am not sure what this involves" - instantiating a class means to create an instance of it. Like `Car theCar = new Car();`

Answer (score 2):

```
public Car(int seatNumber, int numberMade, int yearMade) {
    this.seatNumber = 4;
    this.numberMade = 1500000;
    this.yearMade= 1990;
    this.topSpeed = 180;
  }
```

This block alone shows you don't understand the concept of a constructor.

this code should be :

```
public Car(int seatNumber, int numberMade, int yearMade) {
    this.seatNumber = seatNumber; // takes the value you pass as parameter
    this.numberMade = numberMade; // and stores it into the instance variable
    this.yearMade= yearMade;
    this.topSpeed = 180;          // don't do this, unless you assume to live in a world
// in which every single car has 180 as top speed. pass another parameter for this, or provide setter methods
  }
```

now, here is where it becomes weird.

```
int Car;
    Car = new Vehicle().seatNumber;
    Car = new Vehicle().numberMade;
    Car = new Vehicle().yearMade;

    System.out.println(Car);
```

ehm ... What ya doin'? You are supposed to instantiate a Car, and print that.
What you do, on the other hand, is instantiate an int which you call Car, and set the value to yearMade (the previous values are overwritten)

So: to instantiate a Car:

```
Car myCar = new Car(5, 5000, 2000);
```

Where 5 is the number of seats, 5000 is the number of cars made, and 2000 is the year in which it's made.

Now, you can simply call: `System.out.println(myCar);`
This will call print the String that is returned by the toString method.

EDIT: to avoid an edit stating that you MUST override the toString method:

Yes and no. If you want to printout a nice looking 
"Car specifications: number of seats ... " and so on, you'll need to override the toString method and build the String that you want returned.

However, if you don't override toString, it will still work. It will use the implementation of toString that is inherited from the Object class, which usually is not what you need or want.

Answer (score 0):

`Car` and `Motorbike` is subclass of Vehicle, so whatever your properties defined there will be inherited in subclass.

Override `toSting()` method in `Car` and `Motorbike` class, so when you print object of this class it will display contents present in `toString()` method.

```
@Override
String toString(){

}
```

You have to just pass instance of Car,

```
System.out.println(Car);
```

---

If you are using constructor why you are doing hard coding there, constructor use to initialize the values of object when it created.

So, remove

public Motorbike(int seatNumber, int numberMade, int yearMade) {
    this.seatNumber = 1;
    this.numberMade = 5000;
    this.yearMade= 2015;
    this.topSpeed = 300;
    }

and add one more parameter in your constructor `topSpeed`

```
public Motorbike(int seatNumber, int numberMade, int yearMade, int topSpeed){
    this.seatNumber = seatNumber;
    this.numberMade = numberMade;
    this.yearMade= yearMade;
    this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
}
```

and initialize when you creating object of Motorbike class

```
Motorbike mb = new Motorbike(10,20,2015,80);
```